# Why can't I use getFilesDir(); in a static context?

Tags: android, file, methods, static

I have looked everywhere for an answer and every time I see someone else use the method:

```
getFilesDir();
```

But when I try and use that method in any way, especially:

```
File myFile = new File (getFilesDir();, filename );
```

Eclipse just says, "Cannot make static reference to non-static method getFilesDir from tye ContextWrapper"

I am trying to use it to get the internal directory to write a file for my application.

Thanks!

Comment: you saved my day by getting the file using name and the directory :)

Comment: You've got some invalid code: you can't have a `;` after `getFilesDir()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because in the static method you have not got the object of the class and getFilesDir is not a static method that means it will only be accessible via the object of class Context.

So what you can do is store the reference to the object in a static variable of your class and then use that in your static method.

for example:

```
static YourContextClass obj;

static void method(){
   File myFile = new File (obj.getFilesDir(), filename );
}
```

also you will have to store the reference to the object in your onCreateMethod()

```
 obj = this;
```

The best way to achieve this is

```
 static void method(YourContextClass obj){
      File myFile = new File (obj.getFilesDir(), filename );
 }
```

Comment: Hmm, Now it gives a NullPointerException when it is called?

Comment: That is, now it compiled but it crashes when it is called.

Comment: Did you call the method before your Activity is created? in the Oncreate method the object needs to be initialized..

Comment: Hmm, yes it was called before the onCreate() can I move the obj = this; to the method its self or to a different class (This method is being called froma different class)

Comment: If that other class is a derived class from Context i.e. an Activity and then you can pass the object of that class in the method and use its method ...see my updated answer also that would be the best way of doing

Comment: Am I able to just write the file directory instead?

Comment: as in instead of write getFilesDir() couldnt I just write the directory:"data/data/com.example.referencetool/files"?

Comment: Yes you can do that as well, but it will be a bad idea to hard code the file directory path...

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that and it didnt work either. I am just going to try using sharedPreferences instead.

Comment: what about passing the object of your context class?

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing a log system files, so I created a new class and I wanted to was for all my application and having many instances of this class doing different logs. So I thought that I should create protected or public objects of my class on the application class that is similar to a singleton class.

So I had something like this:

```
      public class MyApp extends Application {
        protected LogApp logApp = new LogApp(getFilesDir());
```

When i called it from my main class to get the list files for example:

```
      public class LogApp {
         public File dirFiles;
         
         //file parameter can't be null, the app will crash
         public LogApp(File file){
            dirFiles = file;
         }

         public File[] getListFiles(){
            return dirFiles.listFiles()
         }

      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            MyApp myApp = (MyApp)getApplicationContext();
            File file[] = myApp.logApp.getListFiles();
      }
```

This was getting me an `NullPointerException`.
The solution in this case was so easy that i felt stupid and proud at the same time.

I couldn't call to `getFilesDir()` in `MyApp`'s declaration space because at that moment there isn't a context to get that directory. The order of execution in an Android App is: Application --> Activity. Like it's said in the Android Manifest file.

Solution? Create my object in my `onCreate()` method of my `MyApp` class, so it looks like this:

```
    public class MyApp extends Application {
        protected LogApp logApp; 
        
        void onCreate(){
           logApp = new LogApp(getFilesDir());
```

So now I can use it in my main class in the same way I did it because there is an instance of my `MainActivity` that extends in last instance from the Context class.

Maybe I'm wrong with my explanation and this is not what is really happening in meanings of terminology and how works Android. If someone understand better than me why this works I invite you to clear up our doubts.